# SharePoint Database Compatibility mode After Upgrade - What is the Best Practice?

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, migration, sql-server, psconfig, upgrade-sharepoint

I upgraded a SharePoint Site Collection DB from SQL 2012/SharePoint 2013 to SQL 2016/SharePoint 2016.  Compatibility mode still shows 2012.  Should I change compatibility mode to SQL 2016 and run psconfig?  What is the best practice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would not change this. There is no reason to.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should run the psconfig only if you want to probably backup restore this database to some other one..

Otherwise there is no need to do so. However if you are going to backup and restore this database, it will give you Compatibility problems if you do not run the psconfig.